A Small Detail in the Derivation of Potential Difference between Two Wires
In Power Systems Analysis, Grainger and Stevenson use the following definition of voltage (p173)

to derive Vab (p174)

between the two wires a and b of a transmission line (p175) whose cross sections are shown below:

Why is the argument of the first logarithm $$\frac{D}{r_a}$$ instead of $$\frac{D-r_b}{r_a}$$
The authors assume "the uniformly distributed charge on the wire is equivalent to a charge concentrated at the center of the wire" (p172). If the denominator ra is the distance between the center of conductor a and the charge on conductor a, then the numerator should be the distance between the center of conductor a to the charge on conductor b which is D - rb.
P.S. Is this question better suited for Physics SE?

I think your equations moved the center points of  "a" and "b".

In the integral shown, D_1 is r_a because the charge of conductor a lies on the surface of conductor a. Given that the charge of conductor b lies on the surface of conductor b, D_2 should net out the radius of conductor b. I believe there is no "moving of center points" in this line of reasoning.

Disclaimer: I do a lot of assumptions because I have no access to the book. E.g., I assume that we are really looking for the voltage between the two wires and not the potential different for any arbitrary position relative to the two wires. Lets do a quick check first:
Lets assume that $$r_a = r_b = r, q_a = q_b = q (1)$$
I drop the constants for the sake of easiness. Lets start with the formular you suggest:
$$q_a \ln\frac{D - r_b}{r_a} + q_b \ln\frac{r_b}{D} \\
\stackrel{(1)}{=} q \ln\frac{D - r}{r} + q \ln\frac{r}{D} \\
= q (\ln(D-r)- \ln r + \ln r - \ln D) \\
= q \ln\frac{D-r}{D} = q \ln(1-\frac{r}{D}) ~ (2) $$
In comparison for the cited formula:
$$q_a \ln\frac{D}{r_a} + q_b \ln\frac{r_b}{D} \\
\stackrel{(1)}{=} q \ln\frac{D}{r} + q \ln\frac{r}{D} \\
=q(\ln D - \ln r + \ln r - \ln D) \\
= 0 ~ (3)$$
But which answer is the resonable one? If both wires are equaly charged, both should have the same potential, thus no potential difference is expected between both. No matter the distance (if D > r). (2) shows a dependency on both, the radius and the distance. (3) on the other hand is always zero for the assumed case (1).
To extend on that. Do we expect the voltage difference between the wires to depend on their distance, even if (1) is not true? Here comes the cited "the uniformly distributed charge on the wire is equivalent to a charge concentrated at the center of the wire" into play. Lets drop the third dimensions and focus on 2D. If one looks at the electric field from far away it makes not difference, if e.g. the radius is doubled and the charge density is halved as long as the total charge in the considered wire stays the same. Pushing that to the extrem one can let r go against zero while the density goes towards infinite. In the limit one replaces the idealized wire with a point charge (in 2D). Both have the same E field from far away. And the potential difference (i.e., voltage) between both wires can be modeled as two "point charges" at distance D (in 2D).
Reason why both models are equal under the made assumptions is that in an extended wire for every volume which is "closer", you will find another volume which is "exactly the same amount further away".
Another way to look at it:
$$ U_{ab} = U_a - U_b \propto q_a \ln\frac{D}{r_a} - q_b \ln\frac{D}{r_b} = q_a \ln\frac{D}{r_a} + q_b \ln\frac{r_b}{D}$$

If (1) is not true and one wire has more charge, I would indeed expect the voltage between the wires to depend on distance as voltage = electric field x distance

But (3) is extremely convincing. Thank you Christian

One has to be careful to not mix up "el. potential" and "el. potential difference". Your statement is correct if one looks at the "el. potential". There is the analogy to "height". While the height might change along the way, it is only important at which height one starts and arrives - putting friction etc aside. For the given example, it does not matter at which total height or distance the start and end points are. Only the height difference is relevant if one want to move a charge from start to end.
